# How do I enable my innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to enable innodb on my ubuntu server 10.04 and having tons of problems, I have tried posting questions everywhere and I have no answers....i tried this

```
show variables like "%innodb%"; +-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| have_innodb           | NO    |
| ignore_builtin_innodb | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

so it seems like it is not installed or something but i keep reading its installed by default

```
show engines;+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I dont see it in the output...any help would really help...this is the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgc5C.png) i keep getting and i cant get past this screen on my socialengine install
Please anyone help

Comment: You should ask this question on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: try the following

http://serverfault.com/questions/143805/unable-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql-on-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: I have tried all those responses and nothing worked in my situation

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/47356/how-do-i-enable-my-innodb

(but I cannot mark cross-stack-exchange-duplicates as such)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue

enabling the following two InnoDB directives in your "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" file appears to have resolved this issue:

```
default-storage-engine=innodb
default-table-type=innodb
```

When restarting your MySQL server, there appears to have been some lingering processes so the "mysqld.sock" file wasn't being created correctly. As you saw in Lish, I forcefully killed the lingering processes using the "kill" command, and then restarted MySQL normally with "service mysql start" which allowed the "mysqld.sock" file to be created.